# Update a label with the file's name, AFTER the file has been selected in the dile directory

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

Before a file is selected, the GUI will have a blank space where the file's name should be. After the file is selected, the GUI should update, and the name of the file selected should be displayed. I have made many different attempts at this, and the program does execute properly, however the name of the file is not displayed. I will show, as best I can, what the GUI should looke like before and after the file is selected

I have tried setting a `StringVar()` and having the label it is associated with update appropriately, however it has not worked so far. If I had to guess what was wrong, I would guess that the window ins't updating properly, but I am not sure.

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import StringVar
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import filedialog

#Wraps two functions inside an object which allows both functions to use filename#
class PDFSelector:
    #Allows user to select PDF to use in program#
    def select_PDF(self):
        #Opens file directory to select a file, and shows both folders and PDF files only# 
        #This should be what changes lbl1a below to the name of the file selected)
        self.filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir = "/", title = "Select file", filetypes = (("pdf files", "*.pdf"), ("all files", "*.*")))
        file_name.set(self.filename)
        window.update_idletasks()
        window.update()

#----Main----#

#Creates an instance of the wrapped functions to use the GUI#        
selector = PDFSelector()

#Creats the GUI that will be used to select inputs#
window = tk.Tk()
window.geometry("600x130")
window.title("Word Frequency Program")
window.resizable(0, 0)

#Just a simple label on the GUI# 
#The name of the file should appear next to "File Selected" AFTER the file has been selected by the user
lbl1 = tk.Label(window, text = "File Selected: ")
lbl1.grid(row = 1, column = 1)
file_name = StringVar()
lbl1a = tk.Label(window, textvariable = file_name)
lbl1a.grid(row = 1, column = 2)

#Calls the select_PDF method to choose a PDF for the program to read#
button1 = ttk.Button(window, text = "Select File", command = selector.select_PDF)
button1.grid(row = 1, column = 4)

window.mainloop()
window.destroy()
```

GUI should display the name of the file

Comment: You've posted way too much code. Please try to reduce this down to a [mcve]. For example, if the problem is with updating a label when you select a file, all we need is the label, the file selector, and enough code to make it run,. We don't need all of the other Button, Label, and Entry widgets.

Comment: Roger that, will reduce this code, and will recude the amount of code for all future posts.

Comment: @Bryan Oakley I reduced the code. I'm still new to posting questions on stack overflow, so I appreciate you not chastising me for posting so much.

Comment: Your code is working for me. When I pick a name, the label is updated.

Comment: So when you select a PDF from your file directory, the label is updated to the name of that file?

Comment: yes, that is what happens.

Comment: Could there be another sort of problem, such as the coding application I’m using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the code does work, however there is something on my end that does not display the updated name of the PDF selected. This is for anyone who finds this question in the future, that the code I wrote works.